# preg_replace undefined variable error

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove currency symbols from a string, but getting an 'undefined variable' error. Sorry if this is totally dumb, I'm a newbie!

```
<? if ($event->ticket_cost) : ?>
   <? $cost = $event->ticket_cost ?>
   <? $cost = preg_replace("€£$","", $cost) ?>
   <?=$cost ?>
   <? else : ?>
   <? echo '' ?>
<? endif ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you are missing dilimiters in `preg_replace()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use delimitters:

```
preg_replace("#€£\$#","", $cost) ?>
```

Also since `$` is special character in regex, you need to escape it with backslash like above.

Also you are using `<?`, it should be `<?=` or better `<?php` unless you are not using any other specialized setting or stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You have three things wrong:

- Missing [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) from regexp (so it should be: `"~€£$~"`)
- `$` is variable stat name in php (evaluted in double quotes too), so either escape it with `\`: `"~€£\$~"` or use `'` (single quot) `'~€£$~'`
- `$` is [meta character](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) in PCRE expressions responsible for end of line therefor it must be escaped so final regexp would look like: `"~€£\\\$~"` or: `'~€£\\$~'`

And one more thing, why won't you use "dumb string substitution" (for example [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)) which should have better performance and it'll make more clear what you want to do, example:

```
$test = "sum € sum 2 £ sum 3$";
$repl = array(
    '€' => '',
    '£' => '',
    '$' => '');
echo strtr( $test, $repl) . "\n";
```

<sub>AFAIK `str_replace()` would iterate trough string 3 times, `strtr()` just once.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/[€£$]/","", $cost) ?>
```

note: storing the price and currency in one field is not a good idea